# Windows Phone. Result of ReadToEndAsync() corrupted by app deactivation

Tags: c#, async-await, windows-phone, streamreader

I've got some troubles with **StreamReader.ReadToEndAsync()**;

```
//some get response code ...
using (var response = getResponseTask.Result)
{
  using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
  {
    using (var responseStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
    {
     var readToEndTask = responseStreamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
     var responseResult = await readToEndTask;
     //and some json parse code here
    }
  }
}
```

So, when I press the Home button on the device (whatever phone or emulator) while ReadToEndAsync task is in process, result string is not full length on app reactivation... i.e. it's ending just cut out without any exceptions or warning.

As result, I can't parse my json-data to object.

How can I fix it or avoid this situation ?

Thanks everybody in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you need to run your code as a background task. Background tasks will run even your app is deactivated. You can refer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/support-your-app-with-background-tasks to learn background tasks.
There are two types of background tasks, in process & out process.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try. 
But is this behaviour of StreamReader normal and well-known? Or is it broken or something?  Because after reactivation `readToEndTask` object have RanToCompletion status with null exception property like nothing bad happens... I mean, does really everybody solve this problem by integrating background tasks in their projects? Damn weird.

Comment: To me this is not weird, This is the OS behavior. OS wont allow you to run tasks continuously even your app is in background. This is to save your device from unnecessary usage of Power, Memory and other resources. So In general your app will not run tasks when in background. Though OS allows you to perform task in background which are really necessary for your apps. With some limitations and providing some configurations you can run tasks in background to solve your purpose.